# How do i restrict the text character limit for quill editor to maximum 5000 characters in angularJS?

Tags: angularjs, quill, maxlength

This is my html code. How do i limit the user to input maximum 5000 characters.

```html
<div class="ql-container ql-bubble" id="richTextQuel">
  <ng-quill-editor theme="bubble" id="richTextEditor" placeholder="Inclusions" ng-model="title" modules="richTextEditorModules" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-isolate-scope 
                             ng-not-empty">
  </ng-quill-editor>
</div>
```

Comment: simple: `maxlength="5000"`, or you can limit the length for your model whenever it's changed, to detect that use `ng-change="checkLength(title)"` (with a custom function)

Answer (score 1):

refer doc [text-change](https://quilljs.com/docs/api/#text-change)

Markup Code:-

```
<div class="ql-container ql-bubble" id="richTextQuel">
   <ng-quill-editor theme="bubble" id="richTextEditor" placeholder="Inclusions" ng-model="title" modules="richTextEditorModules" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-isolate-scope ng-change="textChanged($event)"
   ng-not-empty">
   </ng-quill-editor>
</div>
```

Js Code:-

```
var limit = 5000;
quill.on('text-change', function(delta, old, source) {
    if (quill.getLength() > limit) {
        quill.deleteText(limit, quill.getLength());
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi, Sorry but i'm not much familiar with quill editor. Can u pls tel where that JS code has to be put? in parent js file or the JS file which the html page uses or some directive js file.?

Comment: @Omkar you need to add Js Code in your controller file.... & markup code in html file...

Comment: once i add this code in my js file it gives error that quill is not defined even aft injecting quill

Comment: Is the above JS code which u provided present in the link?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution for Angular 2+ and PrimeNG, but you can change it to fit your solution:

```
this.editor.getQuill().root.addEventListener('keydown', ($event) => this.checkLength($event));
```

Where checkLength is:

```
checkLength($event) {
    if (this.editor.getQuill().root.innerHTML.length >= 15) {
        $event.preventDefault();
    }
}
```